# Consuming useful information on server error with Ember data

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

How are people updating their Apps if an ember data request fails?

To illustrate:

```
this.get('foo').save().then(function(result){

}).catch(function(error){

    //1) how do I know what the server response code was?
    //     (error - does not contain the status code)

    //assume 'foo' save failed because 'bar' model changed on the server
    //2) if I wanted to pass updated 'bar' from the server on failure how can I get
    //     Ember data to update the model?        

});
```

My solution so far which works for 1) but it's a bit hacky and I would prefer a more idiomatic way of deal with this.

```
App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.ActiveModelAdapter.extend({
    ajaxError: function(jqXHR) {
       var response = this._super(jqXHR);
       response.status = jqXHR.status;
       return response;
    }
});
```

Comment: handle the [`error`](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/loading-and-error-substates/#toc_code-error-code-substates) event in your `ApplicationRoute`. Somewhere in the error response you'll have properties stating or hinting the errors, probe the JSON response and find the properties you need to do your thing

Comment: @MilkyWayJoe: When ember data handles the error for some reason it does not pass through the jqXHR object including the status and other potentially relevant info for consumers to act on.  Therefore every error will appear identical to consumers.